# Apache Flink. Windowing with Water Marks

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, windowing

I'm trying to aggregate 60 seconds data keyed by its minute timestamp with maximum 30 seconds delay.

```
DataStream<OHLChelp> ohlcAggStream = stockStream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(30))).map(new mapStockToOhlcHelp()).keyBy((KeySelector<OHLChelp, Long>) o -> o.getMinTime())
            .timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
            .reduce(new aggregateOHLC());
//map complex object to simpler one
DataStream<OHLCmodel> ohlcStremAggregated = ohlcAggStream.map(new mapOHLCredToOHLCfin());
//log ohlc stream
ohlcStreamAggregated.writeAsText(outLogPath);
```

I'm recieving data. Watermarks and timestamps are setting. t seems, aggregated data are never sent to ohlcStreamAggregated and therefore they are not logged.

```
public TimestampExtractor(Time maxDelayInterval) {
        if (maxDelayInterval.toMilliseconds() < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This parameter must be positive or 0.);
        }
        this.maxDelayInterval = maxDelayInterval.toMilliseconds() / 1000;
        this.currentMaxTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE + this.maxDelayInterval;
    }

@Override
public final Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        // set maximum delay 30 seconds
        long potentialWM = currentMaxTimestamp - maxDelayInterval;
        if (potentialWM > lastEmittedWM) {
            lastEmittedWM = potentialWM;
        }
        return new Watermark(lastEmittedWM);
    }
@Override
public final long extractTimestamp(StockTrade stockTrade, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(stockTrade.getTime());
        long timestamp = bd.longValue();
        //set the maximum seen timestamp so far
        if (timestamp > currentMaxTimestamp) {
            currentMaxTimestamp = timestamp;
        }
        return timestamp;
    }
```

I used [this example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/timestamps/BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.java#L72) as a template.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to diagnose your application if you could share the whole thing (maybe in a gist), but, did you:

- set the time characteristic to event time ([docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/event_time.html#setting-a-time-characteristic))?
- call execute on the stream execution environment?

Also, your timestamp extractor could be quite a bit simpler. Something more like this:

```
public static class TimestampExtractor extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<StockTrade> {
    public TimestampExtractor() {
        super(Time.seconds(30));
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(StockTrade trade) {
        return trade.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I set  env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime); and env.execute("Trades from Kafka topic"); As the first collecting stream is working fine, logging and so on, I think the issue is with the windowing. If you could send me your email, we can discuss it further. Much obliged.